# serialEvent only read 63Bytes and this is not the complete data incoming

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

hi everybody im working in a software for a pcb based in the chip ATmega2560
im use this with Xbee in API MODE, so im driving short string data and long string data.
with the short data i dont have any problem but my long data is of 78bytes.

so the serial event only show me 63 bytes and i dont find reason for it.

this is the complete block:

```
void serialEvent2(){
while (Serial2.available()){
    frameReceived[n] = Serial2.read(); 
    Serial.print("  ");
    Serial.print(frameReceived[n], HEX);                
    n++;
    //Serial.print("\t" + String(n));
   /* if (n == (frameReceived[1]+frameReceived[2]) + 4){
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println((frameReceived[1]+frameReceived[2])+4);
        Serial.println("IF");
    }*/
    if ( n == 3 ){
        lfr = frameReceived[2] + 4;
    } 

    if (n == lfr){
        receivedDone = true;
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("[INFO] N: ");
        Serial.println(n);
        Serial.print("[INFO] LFR: ");
        Serial.println(lfr);
    }


    if (receivedDone){
        clearValuesToReceiveFrame();
        processFrame();
        receivedDone = false;
    }                
}


Serial.println();
Serial.println("[While]n:");
Serial.println(n);
Serial.println("[While]LFR: ");
Serial.println(lfr);
n=0;
lfr=0;
```

}

in this block i learn to the programe that the posion 2 in my array is the lenght of the frame in API MODE:

```
        if ( n == 3 ){
        lfr = frameReceived[2] + 4;
    }
```

here i learn to the programe that the n number of bytes have to equal lfr (lengh of the data). if this is true my flags gonna work.

```
        if (n == lfr){
        receivedDone = true;
        Serial.println();
        Serial.print("[INFO] N: ");
        Serial.println(n);
        Serial.print("[INFO] LFR: ");
        Serial.println(lfr);
    }


    if (receivedDone){
        clearValuesToReceiveFrame();
        processFrame();
        receivedDone = false;
    }                
}
```

the problem is that the program only rad 63 n number and my LFR is diferent so the flags never going true, n numbers ever is 63 from 78 real bytes :(
please help me.

Comment: serialEvent is called after the loop(). if your loop() takes time, the Serial receive buffer overflows

Comment: ok i read about it and yeah it is called to the final row in the loop, but any solution for it?look an another way to get the data?

Comment: write the code so that the loop() can loop. slow nested loops can always be integrated into the main loop. function can remember the last state of their work in static variables. If I am not mistaken, your sketch has a function which draws to a display in some `for` loop. remove the for loop, make the incremental variable static and return from the function after every increment. this way the sketch will multitask, drawing to display and reading Serial in time.

Comment: thank you bro, is a little bit hard to implement because i dont see a sample, but i'll try, thankk you